# $\sum\limits_{\text{prime }p} 2^{-p}$ is an irrational number

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

I need help to prove the following result.

> $\displaystyle\sum_{\text{prime }p} 2^{-p}$ is an irrational number.

Comment: Could you provide a source or any context?

Comment: no, is part of an homework.

Comment: Then could you kindly tag it as such?

Answer (score 19):

Hint: Consider this number in base 2.  If it is rational, it must have a period.  What sort of consequence does this mean, that would lead to a contradiction?

Comment: The problem with homework is that we don't know what point the student is supposed to be starting from. Rational numbers have period in binary expansions. Either the questioner was told this in class less than a week ago, in which case he is lazy, and you just did all his work for him. Or he is supposed to discover and prove this himself, in which case your answer and the others on this page (@Potato and @marty_cohen) only just get him started.

Comment: "Or he is supposed to discover and prove this himself" that is the case!

Answer (score 12):

If the $2$'s were replaced by $10$'s, the problem is clear. The decimal expansion of any rational number either terminates or repeats. The number in question is one that has $1$s at all prime places after the decimal point and zeros elsewhere. This does not terminate or repeat, so it must be irrational.

The problem you have is similar, except we consider the binary expansion. But the exact same argument works.

Comment: If the decimal terminates, that's really the same thing as it repeating, since it is just repeating zeros after that.

Answer (score 6):

One way to show that the sum is irrational
is the well-known fact that there
are arbitrarily long intervals
where there are no primes.
If the sum were rational,
chose the interval longer that the period,
and hello contradiction!

In particular,
$n!+k$ for $k = 2$ to $n$
has no primes, since each element is divisible
by a prime from $2$ to $n$.

This also shows that
$\sum_{\text{prime }p} m^{-p}$
is irrational for any integer $m \ge 2$.