# Prove that the infinite $\sum_{\text{ p prime}}\frac{1}{2^p}$ is an irrational number.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, irrational-numbers, pigeonhole-principle, dirichlet-series

> Prove that the infinite $\sum_{\text{
> p prime}}\frac{1}{2^p}$
> is an irrational number.

My progress:

- Suppose $$\omega = \sum_{\text{
  p prime}}\frac{1}{2^p}= \frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\dots$$
- Also let $f(x)= x^{th}$ prime

> We will try to show that for $\omega$ and  $\epsilon > 0,$ there is a positive integer $q$ and an integer $p$ such that $0 < |q\omega − p| < \epsilon.$

- Suppose $$\frac{p}{q}= \frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\dots +\frac{1}{2^{f(n)}}$$
- Then we let $$q=2^{f(n)},~~p=2^{f(n)}\left(\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\dots +\frac{1}{2^{f(n)}}\right)$$
- So $$|q\omega − p|= |2^{f(n)}\omega - 2^{f(n)}\left(\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\dots +\frac{1}{2^{f(n)}}\right)|$$ $$= \frac{2^{f(n)}}{2^{f(n+1)}}+\frac{2^{f(n)}}{2^{f(n+2)}} +\dots$$ $$=\frac{1}{2^{f(n+1)-f(n)}}+\frac{1}{2^{f(n+2)-f(n)}}+\dots \le \frac{1}{2^{f(n+1)-f(n)}}+\frac{1}{2^{f(n+1)-f(n)+1}}+\frac{1}{2^{f(n+1)-f(n)+2}}\dots $$
  $$= \frac{1/2^ {f(n+1)-f(n)}}{1-2^ {f(n+1)-f(n)}}=\frac{1}{2^ {f(n+1)-f(n)}-1}$$

Now, the ending which I think of is that the difference between $f(n+1)-f(n)$ can be very big. Then when we have $f(n+1)-f(n)$ to be very big, then  $1/2^{f(n+1)-f(n)}< \epsilon .$
I was actually motivated by the proof of proving e irrational.

I am not sure about it. Any hints?

Comment: This isn’t going to work. You can approximate rationals arbitrarily well with other rationals. An interesting fact is that all rationals have eventually repeating decimal representations. Use that.

Comment: @Eric: surely you mean _binary_ representations?

Comment: Well, what I thought was when we have $f(n+1)-f(n)$ to be very big, then  $1/2^{f(n+1)-f(n)}< \epsilon .$ I see decimal representation idea is nice, but it didn't strike, I was actually motivated by the proof of proving e irrational, that's why.

Comment: @SunainaPati yes that's a good idea, a large gap cannot happen, however you need to use the denominator to determine how large of a gap becomes impossible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\sum\limits_{\text{prime }p} 2^{-p}$ is an irrational number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396925/sum-limits-textprime-p-2-p-is-an-irrational-number). Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/678985/460967

Comment: It actually could work but whatever I'm out

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since there are arbitrarily large gaps between
consecutive primes
($n!+2$ to $n!+n$
are all composite),
$\sum 2^{-p_i}$
has arbitrarily long strings of $0$'s
in binary and so can not be periodic
which means that it is not  rational.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simpler proof:

By Dirichlet's Theorem on Arithmetic Progressions, for any coprime naturals $a,d$, the arithmetic progression $a+nd$ contains infinitely many primes (and conversely, $a+nd$ for $a,n,d\in\mathbb N$ can only be prime if $a,d$ are coprime). But any arithmetic progression contains infinitely many composites (let $n=ak$ for $k\in\mathbb N$).

This completes the proof, since for a number to be rational, its decimal representation in binary must eventually repeat. Letting $d$ be the period and $a$ some natural such that $a+nd$ contains at least one prime completes the proof.